# UITextView position

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

Is there a way to find ypos in a UITextView, or/and find which row that currently marker is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do some calculation 
 find cursor position by

```
NSRange cursorPosition = [tf selectedRange];
```

substring from cursor position  use this sub string to calculate width of the string by

```
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
```

and then divide it by width of the your TextView width.. it will give you at which line your cursor is... It's logically seems correct... haven't tried it... try it let me know if it is working or not..

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
- (int) getCurrentLine: (UITextView *) textView{
    int pos = textView.selectedRange.location;
    NSString *str =textView.text;
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    int num = pos;
    for (; num< str.length; num++){
        unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:num];
        if ([charset characterIsMember:c]) break;
    }
    str = [str substringToIndex:num];

    CGSize tallerSize =  CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width - 16, 999999);
    CGSize lc1 = [@"Yyg" sizeWithFont: textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize lc = [str sizeWithFont: textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    lc.height = lc.height / lc1.height;
    return lc.height;
}
```